# angular 1.6 with webpack: controller is not registered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I'm writing a small application using angular for frontend, my frontend module has the following structure:

[image]

In my **app.js** I'm defining main angular module:

```
angular.module('weatherApp', []);
```

My controller(**weather.js**) is registering WeatherCtrl:

```
angular.module('weatherApp')
.controller('WeatherCtrl', ['$scope', 'WeatherProvider', ($scope, WeatherProvider) => {
    $scope.location = {
        city: "",
        country: ""
    };

    $scope.options = [
        { label: "Weather", value: "weather" },
        { label: "Forecast", value: "forecast" }
    ];
    $scope.selected = $scope.options[0];

    $scope.result = "Empty";

    $scope.getWeather = function () {
        WeatherProvider.getWeatherFunc($scope.selected.value, $scope.location.city, $scope.location.country)
        .then((response) => {
            $scope.result = response.data;
        })
     }
}]);
```

While serevice(**provider.js**) is registering WeatherProvider:

```
angular.module('weatherApp')
.service('WeatherProvider', ['$http', function($http) {
    this.getWeatherFunc = (weatherMode, city, country) => {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "http://localhost:8080/" + weatherMode + "/" + city + "/" + country
        })
    }
}]);
```

My webpack config looks like:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
   devServer: {
       disableHostCheck: true
   },
   target: 'web',
   context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
   devtool: 'source-map',
   entry: {
       app: "./app.js",
   },
   resolve: {
       modules: [
           path.resolve(__dirname),
           "node_modules"
       ],
       extensions: ['.js', '.html']
   },

   module: {
       loaders: [
           {
               test: /\.js$/,
               exclude: /node_modules/,
               loader: 'babel-loader',
           }
       ]
   },

   output: {
       path: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
       filename: "bundle.js",
       publicPath: "/"
   },

   plugins: [
       new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
           template: __dirname + "/src/index.tmpl.html"
       }),
       new webpack.DefinePlugin({
           'process.env': {
               'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV ||"dev"),
           }
       })
   ],};
```

Here is **index.tmpl.html**:

[image]

Now I'm running npm run dev and **http://localhost:8081/** gives me the following result:

[image]

An error says: Error: $controller:ctrlreg
A controller with this name is not registered.
In the same time **http://localhost:8081/index.tmpl.html** returns the expected result:

[image]

Do you have any idea why my controller and service are not in bundle.js? (I believe this is the main reason of a failure)

Comment: create a plnkr.

Comment: check this tutorial http://angular-tips.com/blog/2015/06/using-angular-1-dot-x-with-es6-and-webpack/

Comment: you need to work around ur app.js file more...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order as

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="service/provider.js"</script>
<script src="controller/weather.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried this option as well, it doesn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I were using a wrong example of webpack config, the following line was not proper for my case:

```
target: 'web'
```

After replacing it with:

```
target: 'node'
```

everything started working as expected.